# Animating a GIF on Canvas using react-konva

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, konvajs, react-konva

I am trying to create a UI for an application using react. I have am using react-konva for creating a 2D canvas. I have figured out how to import an image onto this canvas but am having trouble trying to animate a gif. There is documentation for how to do it in konva but I can't seem to be able to convert it to react-konva.

The documentation to do it in konva is given [here](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/GIF_On_Canvas.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Stage, Layer, Image } from "react-konva";
// gifler will be imported into global window object
import "gifler";

const GIF = ({ src }) => {
  const imageRef = React.useRef(null);
  const canvas = React.useMemo(() => {
    const node = document.createElement("canvas");
    return node;
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // save animation instance to stop it on unmount
    let anim;
    window.gifler(src).get(a => {
      anim = a;
      anim.animateInCanvas(canvas);
      anim.onDrawFrame = (ctx, frame) => {
        ctx.drawImage(frame.buffer, frame.x, frame.y);
        imageRef.current.getLayer().draw();
      };
    });
    return () => anim.stop();
  }, [src, canvas]);

  return <Image image={canvas} ref={imageRef} />;
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
        <Layer>
          <GIF src="https://konvajs.org/assets/yoda.gif" />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-gif-animation-p86qr